# Proving a language is nonregular with Myhill-Nerode theorem

Tags: formal-languages

I am trying to figure out how to prove a language that is nonregular with using Myhill-Nerode theorem.

Here I have

> x^​n y^​n x^​n = {xyx xxyyxx xxxyyyxxx ...}

How would I be able to do this ? Would I just say , the language is nonregular because here we observe that the strings xyx xxyyxx xxxyyyxxx... are all in different classes ?

Comment: Yes, for each $n\in\mathbb{Z}$, $x^ny^nx^n$ belongs to a different class (I guess you have to show why). So, the number of classes is not finite.